# how to display google maps using api to clients using the internet through a proxy

Tags: javascript, django, google-maps, proxy

I have a client who access the internet through a proxy server. The google map fails to load on his computer. How do I display the map.

I know his proxy address.

Should I make any changes to the javascript code.

Or should I make any changes in the backend code (written in Django).

Comment: No to both. This is not something you can control.

Comment: Sorry, the problem was with the backend. Fixed it.